# currentStateChange and currentStateChanging do not fire in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I wanted to use the currentStateChange event in my application but whatever code being called in this event was not executed so I thought may be there's something wrong with my code so I tried testing it on one of the examples in adobe live docs.
So I took this example 
[here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/transitions_3.html#209003)

```
<mx:states>
    <mx:State name="One">
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p1}" name="x" value="110"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p1}" name="y" value="0"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p1}" name="width" value="200"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p1}" name="height" value="210"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p2}" name="x" value="0"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p2}" name="y" value="0"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p2}" name="width" value="100"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p2}" name="height" value="100"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p3}" name="x" value="0"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p3}" name="y" value="110"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p3}" name="width" value="100"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p3}" name="height" value="100"/>
    </mx:State>
    <mx:State name="Two">
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p2}" name="x" value="110"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p2}" name="y" value="0"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p2}" name="width" value="200"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p2}" name="height" value="210"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p3}" name="x" value="0"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p3}" name="y" value="110"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p3}" name="width" value="100"/>
        <mx:SetProperty target="{p3}" name="height" value="100"/>
    </mx:State>
</mx:states>

<!-- Define Transition array with one Transition object.-->
<mx:transitions>
    <!-- A transition for changing from any state to any state. -->
    <mx:Transition id="myTransition" fromState="*" toState="*">
        <!-- Define a Parallel effect as the top-level effect.-->
        <mx:Parallel id="t1" targets="{[p1,p2,p3]}">
            <!-- Define a Move and Resize effect.-->
            <mx:Move  duration="400"/>
            <mx:Resize duration="400"/>
        </mx:Parallel>
    </mx:Transition>
</mx:transitions>

<!-- Define the Canvas container holding the three Panel containers.-->
<mx:Canvas id="pm" width="100%" height="100%" >
    <mx:Panel id="p1" title="One" 
            x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"
            click="currentState='One'" currentStateChange="Alert.show('change')" currentStateChanging="Alert.show('changing')" >
        <mx:Label fontSize="24" text="One"/>
    </mx:Panel>

    <mx:Panel id="p2" title="Two" 
            x="0" y="110" width="100" height="100"
            click="currentState='Two'" >
        <mx:Label fontSize="24" text="Two"/>
    </mx:Panel>

    <mx:Panel id="p3" title="Three" 
            x="110" y="0" width="200" height="210" 
            click="currentState=''" >
        <mx:Label fontSize="24" text="Three"/>
    </mx:Panel>
</mx:Canvas>
```

And all what I did is placing an alert in both events currentStateChange and currentStateChanging of panel One and I didn't get the alerts when clicking on the panel.
I also tried replacing the inline code with a call to a function that makes the alert also nothing happened.

What's wrong with what I am trying to do here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are listening for state changes of `p1`, but you never change the state of that panel: `p1.currentState` stays the same. States are not automatically inherited or something like that.
If you want to see the state change, add the listener on the container you are setting the state of. In the example you are linking to that is on the Application tag.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the part of currentState as I thought that click="currentState='One'" changes the currentState of p1 from the base state to state "One" and not the state of the container.

Thanks the event is now working when I moved it to the application tag.